# How to call a javascript function by month, on blogger

Tags: javascript, blogger

I would like to call a javascript function that shows random comments on blogger.

Based on the current month, I would like to make random comments of different posts.

If I use this code it returns error because of I use the `<script>` tag many times.

How could I solve?

```
<script>
 
if (month<=6)
{
    document.write('<script src="/feeds/24125792518438636/comments/default?max-results=1&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=getRandom"></script>');
}
else
{
    document.write('<script src="/feeds/21504002289237804/comments/default?max-results=1&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=getRandom"></script>');
}
 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to put your JavaScript in a file and call that from your script tag. For example, if you created a file called `javascript.js`:

`<script src="javascript.js"></script>`

See this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) for more details.

Comment: the problem is that i want to call a javascript function with those parameters